# Service Temporarily Unavailable Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

**503: Service Temporarily Unavailable**

Too many IP addresses accessing one secure area!

Please contact Support if you need assistance.

I am not able to Open admin page and I am not even able to see any sort of errors on then page. How do I resolve this? Please Help...

Comment: The issue has been spotted, its due to s2Member plugin. Please check the comment by the person who have asked the question, to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a backup of all your plugins and delete all from the plugin area.

Install plugins one by one and check which plugin is causing trouble.

Most probably it might be caused due to any plugins like s2Member.

If it is s2Member plugin you can solve the issue from here:

Dashboard -› s2Member® -› Restriction Options -› Unique IP Access Restrictions

Comment: Yes I'm using s2Member plugin. How to fix this issue